# Error with substring seperating data by char(10)+char(13) line breaks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, substring

What I am attempting to do is separate my data by the line breaks into separate fields: **Attn, Addr1Field, Addr2Field**. I have found the location of both of the line breaks but the difference isn't the same for every row of data so I'm using the expression as the third option in my `Substring()` function. I'm getting the error `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function`. In the attached image I hardcoded 34-20 to get my desired results but each row has the possibility to be different so I need to be able to use the expression.
[image]

```
Select   
case  
when LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), soship.fmstreet),5)='ATTN:'   
Then SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), soship.fmstreet), 7,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), soship.fmstreet))-1)   
Else ' '   
End as AttnField,    

case   
when LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), soship.fmstreet),5)='ATTN:'   
Then SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), soship.fmstreet),CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), soship.fmstreet))+2,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), soship.fmstreet),CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), soship.fmstreet))+1) - 
CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), soship.fmstreet))) 

Else ''     
End as Addr1Field
```

Comment: `charindex` returns 0 when it does not find anything.

Comment: Images of data are not really helpful. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What can I do to stop it from returning 0?

Comment: Either stop feeding it data that doesn't have what it is looking for, or handle the case where it does not found anything.

Comment: How would I go about handling the issue when it doesn't return anything. A new case statement or adding a criteria to my original?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `charindex` was returning 0 so I wrote a `Where` clause to solve it.

```
Where
(CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), soship.fmstreet),CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), soship.fmstreet))+1) - 
CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), soship.fmstreet)) > 0)
```